# Как ускорить HTML мобильное приложение?

Tags: android, html, cordova

Есть андроид приложение сделанное с помощью cordova, в котором анимации заметно тормозят, да и вообще время отклика заметно выше, чем у нативных приложений. Но при этом тот же код запущенный на том же устройстве через браузер работает превосходно. Как так вышло и как увеличить производительность приложения?

Comment: браузер у Вас скорее всего хром, а cordova использует webview, а это не объязательно одно и тоже.

Что делать? писать приложения по нормальному - либо убирать лишние анимации, либо нативно.

Comment: Что вы хотите от ненативной технологии, такова цена ее использования

Answer (score 1):

Решением проблемы оказался Crosswalk. Работает раза в два быстрее.